# bogus (or not?) warning for UTextAlignmentLeft with AppCode 2.1

Tags: objective-c, appcode

Since 2.1 , i get this warning

[image]

when refering to this ctor method :

[image]

my tired eyes tell me i should not be getting this warning but ... alas still quite new at objc.  Am I missing something fundamental here ?

Answer (score 1):

Please create an issue in the AppCode tracker and provide the details - the declaration of "textMenuItemWithText" method and your SDK version. We couldn't reproduce it on this case:

```
- (void)bar:(UITextAlignment)alignment {
}

-(void)foo {
    [self bar:UITextAlignmentLeft];
}
```